# Multiple Subscriptions causing slow write to clustered topic

Tags: performance, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

We have two IBM MQ Queue Managers in AWS (EC2, EFS, multi-instanced). They are in a cluster, and have clustered topics (Direct, not Topic Hosts) defined. There about forty topics in all, but only about 3 of them are heavily used. All topics are defined on both qmgrs.

We then have a feed of messages into one of the two queue managers, written via a remote queue to the topic over a sender/receiver channel. Most of the flows are just a couple of messages a minute or so, but some are 1 per second or even 10 per second (but only 50 characters per message body).

Each clustered topic has a local subscription on each queue manager, pointing to a local queue (for testing purposes). MQ then creates proxy subscriptions automatically on both queue managers - one for each topic string being subscribed to.

Additionally, a few of the topics have an MQ JMS client (Websphere Application Server) subscribing on the first queue manager, and the second queue manager is configured as a "parent" in a topic hierarchy, over a sender/receiver channel to a third party queue manager, which has the topics defined locally so they can subscribe there too (again, we see proxy subscriptions being set up on the second qmgr for this).

What we found is, once we turned on the high-volume flow (non-persistent messages), messages were backing up on the `SYSTEM.INTER.QMGR.PUBS` queue on the second qmgr, and on the `SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.CLUSNAME.QM2` queue on the first queue manager.

Removing our local subscription to the topic from qmgr2 then allowed the backlog to clear.

Looking at the servers, the disk IO, CPU and RAM are all fine - it's not like we're running out of IO or something.

So, my question is, why would having multiple subscriptions to a topic cause the write to that topic to severely slow?

---

Having tested further, it's only having a write to a local queue that causes the issue - so something to do with the disk, perhaps? But we're nowhere near any IO throughput thresholds on the EFS.

Comment: What version of MQ?

Comment: It seems like that the mini loop you created in the topic hierarchy is amplified by the clustered topics. Do you see duplicate deliveries of publications?

Comment: Is there any chance that you are having delivery problems with the local subscription (subscription queue full or somesuch since it is just for testing and maybe nothing is reading from it)? Does changing the NPMSGDLV setting on the topic to bypass failures to deliver (or using a DLQ) help?

Comment: We're using MQ 9.2.x and not seeing duplicates. @MoragHughson no, the queues aren't full - we've got expiries set on the queues so they automatically expire off within 10 minutes, well before they fill up. We have a DLQ, and I'll try changing NPMSGDLV on the topic, thanks.